# How to set the max mint per wallet

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721

I have a collection of 10K and i want to set the Max mint per wallet on two phases of the mint, 5k free mint with Max 3 Nfts/wallet and 5k with cost of 0.05ETH no limit.

```
SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.9 <0.9.0;

import 'erc721a/contracts/extensions/ERC721AQueryable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol';

contract OREDO is ERC721AQueryable, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

  using Strings for uint256;

  string public uriPrefix = '';
  string public uriSuffix = '.json';
  
  uint256 public cost;
  uint256 public maxSupply;

  bool public paused = true;
  bool public revealed = true;

  constructor(
    string memory _tokenName,
    string memory _tokenSymbol,
    uint256 _cost,
    uint256 _maxSupply
  ) ERC721A(_tokenName, _tokenSymbol) {
    setCost(_cost);
    maxSupply = _maxSupply;
  }

  modifier mintCompliance(uint256 _mintAmount) {
    require(_mintAmount > 0 , 'Invalid mint amount!');
    require(totalSupply() + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, 'Max supply exceeded!');
    _;
  }

  modifier mintPriceCompliance(uint256 _mintAmount) {
    require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, 'Insufficient funds!');
    _;
  }


  function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable mintCompliance(_mintAmount) mintPriceCompliance(_mintAmount) {
    require(!paused, 'The contract is paused!');

    _safeMint(_msgSender(), _mintAmount);
  }
  
  function mintForAddress(uint256 _mintAmount, address _receiver) public mintCompliance(_mintAmount) onlyOwner {
    _safeMint(_receiver, _mintAmount);
  }

  function _startTokenId() internal view virtual override returns (uint256) {
    return 1;
  }

  function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(_tokenId), 'ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token');

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
        ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, _tokenId.toString(), uriSuffix))
        : '';
  }

  function setRevealed(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    revealed = _state;
  }

  function setCost(uint256 _cost) public onlyOwner {
    cost = _cost;
  }

  function setUriPrefix(string memory _uriPrefix) public onlyOwner {
    uriPrefix = _uriPrefix;
  }

  function setUriSuffix(string memory _uriSuffix) public onlyOwner {
    uriSuffix = _uriSuffix;
  }

  function setPaused(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    paused = _state;
  }

  function withdraw() public onlyOwner nonReentrant {
    // =============================================================================
    (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}('');
    require(os);
    // =============================================================================
  }

  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return uriPrefix;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just implement this exact setup with per-wallet mints (Merkle tree), and multiple phases with programmable timing.

Open sourced licensed at https://github.com/LightArtists/light-smart-contracts

Also I have office hours if you have started setting it up but have questions // check out https://phor.net/#hour